# Android Studio: Could not find method implementation()

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, swiperefreshlayout

> ERROR: Could not find method implemenation() for arguments [com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Here's the error, it says for me to install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager.

Backstory:
I am having gradle sync issues on Android Studio when trying to add the implementation for SwipeRefreshLayout. I tried to use version 28 cause my compile sdk version is 28 but it couldn't find it. I believe I'm using Android studio 3 so implementation should be correct.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.codepath.apps.restclienttemplate"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28

        // Room schemas
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ["room.schemaLocation": "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
            }
        }
    }

    // Related to https://github.com/scribejava/scribejava/issues/480
    // Scribe expects Java 7 or this custom Apache library
    lintOptions {
        lintConfig rootProject.file('gradle/lint.xml')
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    implementation 'com.codepath.libraries:android-oauth-handler:1.4.0'
    implementation 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    // Glide for remote image loading
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
    // Android Async Http for sending async network requests
    implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    // Room for simple persistence with an ORM
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1"
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"
    implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'

    implemenation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is you have used the word **implemenation** for `support-v4:27.1.1` dependency. But the word should be **implementation**.

Try to use updated version

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```

instead of using lower version

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
```

For more short you can use **api** instead of using **implementation**. Like this

```
api 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```

Comment: Oh my gosh, I can't believe it was due to a simple misspelling. Thank you so much for your help! For clarification though, does the application normally crash when using a different support library version versus the compiledsdkversion?

Comment: Should use the same support library version with the compiledSDKVersion. If you use different version its not reproduce any crashing.